# Buffer overflow error in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, debugging, crash

I've been developing a program called RoboJournal for quite some time now. Somebody recently sent me a bug report explaining how the whole program crashes when the Editor window form is displayed while the spellcheck functionality is enabled. However, everything works fine while the spellcheck is disabled in program settings. This bug seems to only affect a specific version of Qt (4.8.3) because I’ve tested the app on 4.7.4 and 4.8.4 and everything works fine. I never noticed the bug prior to this because I wasn't developing the app on 4.8.3. This bug is the main reason why I haven't packaged the app for Debian yet; I plan to include the fix in the next point release.

Whenever I encounter a crashing bug, I normally run the code through a debugger (gdb), set breakpoints, and go through it line by line until I find the problem. However, I can't do that this time because the bug only affects release builds; I tried building the app against the Qt 4.8.3 debug libraries but to my surprise everything worked properly! Apparently, the crash has something to do with the release libraries on that specific version of Qt  but I have no idea what it is. How can I properly debug the app when the only way to experience the problem is with a release build? I tried setting breakpoints on the release build when I ran it through gdb  but that didn't work.

Fortunately, this bug seems to have been fixed in Qt 4.8.4 (and newer, but I haven't tested this on Qt 5 yet) but I still have to figure out a workaround for those who are stuck using 4.8.3. (I can't expect users to roll their own Qt and I have no idea when the Debian folks will update their repos with a new version) Any ideas?

Here's the gdb output from the crash. As far as I can tell, the bug has something to do with libc.so.6:

```
buffer overflow detected ***: /usr/local/bin/robojournal terminated
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__fortify_fail+0x5c)[0x7ffff44fb82c]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x109700)[0x7ffff44fa700]
/usr/local/bin/robojournal[0x49982f]
/usr/local/bin/robojournal[0x49a374]
/usr/local/bin/robojournal[0x49b192]
/usr/local/bin/robojournal[0x49b6da]
/usr/local/bin/robojournal[0x4a947d]
/usr/local/bin/robojournal[0x432e17]
/usr/local/bin/robojournal[0x43529f]
/usr/local/bin/robojournal[0x421afb]
/usr/local/bin/robojournal[0x4ace7b]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4(_ZN11QMetaObject8activateEP7QObjectPKS_iPPv+0x483)[0x7ffff5075123]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtGui.so.4(_ZN15QAbstractButton7clickedEb+0x32)[0x7ffff5bee422]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtGui.so.4(+0x589d2e)[0x7ffff5941d2e]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtGui.so.4(+0x58a560)[0x7ffff5942560]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtGui.so.4(_ZN15QAbstractButton17mouseReleaseEventEP11QMouseEvent+0x8c)[0x7ffff59427cc]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtGui.so.4(_ZN11QToolButton17mouseReleaseEventEP11QMouseEvent+0xa)[0x7ffff59fc99a]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtGui.so.4(_ZN7QWidget5eventEP6QEvent+0x7e0)[0x7ffff55d3850]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtGui.so.4(_ZN19QApplicationPrivate13notify_helperEP7QObjectP6QEvent+0xac)[0x7ffff5583e9c]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtGui.so.4(_ZN12QApplication6notifyEP7QObjectP6QEvent+0x99b)[0x7ffff5588b6b]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4(_ZN16QCoreApplication14notifyInternalEP7QObjectP6QEvent+0x8e)[0x7ffff505f56e]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtGui.so.4(_ZN19QApplicationPrivate14sendMouseEventEP7QWidgetP11QMouseEventS1_S1_PS1_R8QPointerIS0_Eb+0x143)[0x7ffff5584cd3]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtGui.so.4(+0x24a554)[0x7ffff5602554]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtGui.so.4(_ZN12QApplication15x11ProcessEventEP7_XEvent+0xd6f)[0x7ffff560144f]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtGui.so.4(+0x270fa2)[0x7ffff5628fa2]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0(g_main_context_dispatch+0x135)[0x7ffff296cab5]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0(+0x47de8)[0x7ffff296cde8]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0(g_main_context_iteration+0x34)[0x7ffff296cea4]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4(_ZN20QEventDispatcherGlib13processEventsE6QFlagsIN10QEventLoop17ProcessEventsFlagEE+0x66)[0x7ffff508dbf6]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtGui.so.4(+0x270c1e)[0x7ffff5628c1e]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4(_ZN10QEventLoop13processEventsE6QFlagsINS_17ProcessEventsFlagEE+0x2f)[0x7ffff505e2bf]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4(_ZN10QEventLoop4execE6QFlagsINS_17ProcessEventsFlagEE+0x138)[0x7ffff505e548]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4(_ZN16QCoreApplication4execEv+0x88)[0x7ffff5063708]
/usr/local/bin/robojournal[0x412f34]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xed)[0x7ffff441276d]
/usr/local/bin/robojournal[0x413cc1]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-005b0000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 48248                              /usr/local/bin/robojournal
007af000-007b0000 r--p 001af000 08:01 48248                              /usr/local/bin/robojournal
007b0000-007b5000 rw-p 001b0000 08:01 48248                              /usr/local/bin/robojournal
007b5000-00eb3000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
7fffdc000000-7fffdc021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fffdc021000-7fffe0000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fffe16a0000-7fffe16a1000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fffe16a1000-7fffe1ea1000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fffe1ea1000-7fffe215d000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 130                        /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.so.18.0.0
7fffe215d000-7fffe235c000 ---p 002bc000 08:01 130                        /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.so.18.0.0
7fffe235c000-7fffe2362000 r--p 002bb000 08:01 130                        /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.so.18.0.0
7fffe2362000-7fffe23e0000 rw-p 002c1000 08:01 130                        /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.so.18.0.0
7fffe23e0000-7fffe23e5000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fffe23e5000-7fffe23f5000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 4894                       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt4/plugins/sqldrivers/libqsqlmysql.so
7fffe23f5000-7fffe25f5000 ---p 00010000 08:01 4894                       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt4/plugins/sqldrivers/libqsqlmysql.so
7fffe25f5000-7fffe25f6000 r--p 00010000 08:01 4894                       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt4/plugins/sqldrivers/libqsqlmysql.so
7fffe25f6000-7fffe25f7000 rw-p 00011000 08:01 4894                       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt4/plugins/sqldrivers/libqsqlmysql.so
7fffe2648000-7fffe264c000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 10234                      /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/2.10.0/loaders/libpixbufloader-png.so
7fffe264c000-7fffe284c000 ---p 00004000 08:01 10234                      /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/2.10.0/loaders/libpixbufloader-png.so
7fffe284c000-7fffe284d000 r--p 00004000 08:01 10234                      /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/2.10.0/loaders/libpixbufloader-png.so
7fffe284d000-7fffe284e000 rw-p 00005000 08:01 10234                      /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/2.10.0/loaders/libpixbufloader-png.so
7fffe284e000-7fffe286a000 r--s 00000000 08:01 40509                      /usr/share/mime/mime.cache
7fffe286b000-7fffe28cb000 rw-s 00000000 00:04 4620315                    /SYSV00000000 (deleted)
7fffe28cb000-7fffe2afe000 rw-s 00000000 00:04 4587546                    /SYSV00000000 (deleted)
7fffe2afe000-7fffe2ba3000 r--p 00000000 08:01 277820                     /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu/DejaVuSans-Bold.ttf
7fffe2ba3000-7fffe2bae000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 9203                       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjbig.so.0.0.0
7fffe2bae000-7fffe2dad000 ---p 0000b000 08:01 9203                       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjbig.so.0.0.0
7fffe2dad000-7fffe2dae000 r--p 0000a000 08:01 9203                       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjbig.so.0.0.0
7fffe2dae000-7fffe2db1000 rw-p 0000b000 08:01 9203                       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjbig.so.0.0.0
7fffe2db1000-7fffe2e1e000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 9499                       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtiff.so.5.1.0
7fffe2e1e000-7fffe301e000 ---p 0006d000 08:01 9499                       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtiff.so.5.1.0
7fffe301e000-7fffe301f000 r--p 0006d000 08:01 9499                       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtiff.so.5.1.0
7fffe301f000-7fffe3022000 rw-p 0006e000 08:01 9499                       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtiff.so.5.1.0
7fffe3022000-7fffe3029000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 10954                      /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt4/plugins/imageformats/libqtiff.so
7fffe3029000-7fffe3228000 ---p 00007000 08:01 10954                      /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt4/plugins/imageformats/libqtiff.so
7fffe3228000-7fffe3229000 r--p 00006000 08:01 10954                      /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt4/plugins/imageformats/libqtiff.so
7fffe3229000-7fffe322a000 rw-p 00007000 08:01 10954                      /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt4/plugins/imageformats/libqtiff.so
7fffe322a000-7fffe322f000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 10953                      /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt4/plugins/imageformats/libqtga.so
7fffe322f000-7fffe342e000 ---p 00005000 08:01 10953                      /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt4/plugins/imageformats/libqtga.so
7fffe342e000-7fffe342f000 r--p 00004000 08:01 10953                      /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt4/plugins/imageformats/libqtga.so
7fffe342f000-7fffe3430000 rw-p 00005000 08:01 10953                      /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt4/plugins/imageformats/libqtga.so
7fffe3430000-7fffe3484000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 8631                       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtSvg.so.4.8.3
7fffe3484000-7fffe3683000 ---p 00054000 08:01 8631                       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtSvg.so.4.8.3
7fffe3683000-7fffe3685000 r--p 00053000 08:01 8631                       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtSvg.so.4.8.3
7fffe3685000-7fffe3686000 rw-p 00055000 08:01 8631                       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtSvg.so.4.8.3
7fffe3686000-7fffe368b000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 10952                      /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt4/plugins/imageformats/libqsvg.so
7fffe368b000-7fffe388a000 ---p 00005000 08:01 10952                      /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt4/plugins/imageformats/libqsvg.so
7fffe388a000-7fffe388b000 r--p 00004000 08:01 10952                      /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt4/plugins/imageformats/libqsvg.so
7fffe388b000-7fffe388c000 rw-p 00005000 08:01 10952                      /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt4/plugins/imageformats/libqsvg.so
7fffe388c000-7fffe38c1000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 9225                       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblcms.so.1.0.19
7fffe38c1000-7fffe3ac0000 ---p 00035000 08:01 9225                       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblcms.so.1.0.19
7fffe3ac0000-7fffe3ac1000 r--p 00034000 08:01 9225                       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblcms.so.1.0.19
7fffe3ac1000-7fffe3ac2000 rw-p 00035000 08:01 9225                       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblcms.so.1.0.19
7fffe3ac2000-7fffe3ac5000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fffe3ac5000-7fffe3b4f000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 9259                       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmng.so.1.1.0.10
7fffe3b4f000-7fffe3d4f000 ---p 0008a000 08:01 9259                       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmng.so.1.1.0.10
7fffe3d4f000-7fffe3d52000 r--p 0008a000 08:01 9259                       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmng.so.1.1.0.10
7fffe3d52000-7fffe3d54000 rw-p 0008d000 08:01 9259                       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmng.so.1.1.0.10
7fffe3d54000-7fffe3d59000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 10951                      /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt4/plugins/imageformats/libqmng.so
7fffe3d59000-7fffe3f59000 ---p 00005000 08:01 10951                      /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt4/plugins/imageformats/libqmng.so
7fffe3f59000-7fffe3f5a000 r--p 00005000 08:01 10951                      /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt4/plugins/imageformats/libqmng.so
7fffe3f5a000-7fffe3f5b000 rw-p 00006000 08:01 10951                      /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt4/plugins/imageformats/libqmng.so
7fffe3f5b000-7fffe3f9a000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 9207                       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so.8.0.2
7fffe3f9a000-7fffe419a000 ---p 0003f000 08:01 9207                       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so.8.0.2
7fffe419a000-7fffe419b000 r--p 0003f000 08:01 9207                       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so.8.0.2
7fffe419b000-7fffe419c000 rw-p 00040000 08:01 9207                       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so.8.0.2
7fffe419c000-7fffe41ac000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fffe41c2000-7fffe41c9000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 10950                      /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt4/plugins/imageformats/libqjpeg.so
7fffe41c9000-7fffe43c8000 ---p 00007000 08:01 10950                      /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt4/plugins/imageformats/libqjpeg.so
7fffe43c8000-7fffe43c9000 r--p 00006000 08:01 10950                      /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt4/plugins/imageformats/libqjpeg.so
7fffe43c9000-7fffe43ca000 rw-p 00007000 08:01 10950                      /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt4/plugins/imageformats/libqjpeg.so
7fffe43ca000-7fffe43d1000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 10949                      /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt4/plugins/imageformats/libqico.so
7fffe43d1000-7fffe45d0000 ---p 00007000 08:01 10949                      /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt4/plugins/imageformats/libqico.so
7fffe45d0000-7fffe45d1000 r--p 00006000 08:01 10949                      /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt4/plugins/imageformats/libqico.so
7fffe45d1000-7fffe45d2000 rw-p 00007000 08:01 10949                      /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt4/plugins/imageformats/libqico.so
7fffe45d2000-7fffe45d9000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 10948                      /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt4/plugins/imageformats/libqgif.so
7fffe45d9000-7fffe47d8000 ---p 00007000 08:01 10948                      /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt4/plugins/imageformats/libqgif.so
7fffe47d8000-7fffe47d9000 r--p 00006000 08:01 10948                      /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt4/plugins/imageformats/libqgif.so
7fffe47d9000-7fffe47da000 rw-p 00007000 08:01 10948                      /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt4/plugins/imageformats/libqgif.so
7fffe47da000-7fffe47dc000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 10901                      /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pango/1.6.0/modules/pango-basic-fc.so
7fffe47dc000-7fffe49db000 ---p 00002000 08:01 10901                      /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pango/1.6.0/modules/pango-basic-fc.so
7fffe49db000-7fffe49dc000 r--p 00001000 08:01 10901                      /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pango/1.6.0/modules/pango-basic-fc.so
7fffe49dc000-7fffe49dd000 rw-p 00002000 08:01 10901                      /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pango/1.6.0/modules/pango-basic-fc.so
7fffe49dd000-7fffe49e6000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 10648                      /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/engines/libpixmap.so
7fffe49e6000-7fffe4be6000 ---p 00009000 08:01 10648                      /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/engines/libpixmap.so
7fffe4be6000-7fffe4be7000 r--p 00009000 08:01 10648                      /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/engines/libpixmap.so
7fffe4be7000-7fffe4be8000 rw-p 0000a000 08:01 10648                      /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/engines/libpixmap.so
7fffe4be8000-7fffe4c17000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 10647                      /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/engines/libmurrine.so
7fffe4c17000-7fffe4e17000 ---p 0002f000 08:01 10647                      /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/engines/libmurrine.so
7fffe4e17000-7fffe4e18000 r--p 0002f000 08:01 10647                      /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/engines/libmurrine.so
7fffe4e18000-7fffe4e19000 rw-p 00030000 08:01 10647                      /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/engines/libmurrine.so
7fffe4e19000-7fffe4e25000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 5140                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.15.so
7fffe4e25000-7fffe5024000 ---p 0000c000 08:01 5140                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.15.so
7fffe5024000-7fffe5025000 r--p 0000b000 08:01 5140                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.15.so
7fffe5025000-7fffe5026000 rw-p 0000c000 08:01 5140                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.15.so
Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
0x00007ffff4427425 in raise () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to deal with segmentation faults is to analyze stack trace saved into coredump produced by kernel. Most of the distributions have coredump saving disabled, so there is how it can be enabled

```
ulimit -c unlimited
```

Proc file system has several files to configure corudump production. The most important is [core pattern](http://linux.die.net/man/5/core) `/proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern`, which specify coredump name and optionally post-process commands.

When process receives segmentation fault signal, kernel will save it's state in a coredump file, which can be later inspected with [dgb](http://linux.die.net/man/1/gdb):

```
gdb -c core ./binary_which_produced_the_core
bt
```

this will print you a back trace of what the program was doing when segmentation fault has happened.

Also in order to make back trace more informative, you have to install packages with debug symbols. In your case you will need libc, Qt, glib and your own binary symbols. With Qt, glib and libc this is just as easy as

```
sudo apt-get install libc6-dbg libqt4-dbg libglib2.0-0-dbg
```

With Qt binaries it's more complicated, if your build tool is qmake.

```
CONFIG += debug
```

in .pro file will enable debug symbols, however, it will also enable asserts and other checks in the code, making it behave differently.
If you build tool is cmake or autotools than producing debug symbols becomes trivial.